# How can I check if a VHDL Integer is even or odd?

Tags: vhdl

What is the easiest or simplest way to check if an integer signal is even or odd in VHDL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (A mod 2) = 0 then
-- it's even
else
-- it's odd
end if;
```

Comment: ModelSim's compiler will actually complain unless you explicitly write `if((A mod 2) = 0)`, but thanks!

Comment: Huh? This is backwards. If an integer mod 2 = 0 then it's even. (EDIT: I see you corrected it)

Comment: @Martin Thompson: I hadn't noticed that it had been edited the first time. The logic (not syntax) in the original answer was correct. It's available by clicking the edit time.

Comment: @SixHouse: See my comment just above.

Comment: @Jonathan M: Sorry, I agree it would have been better if I'd edited it to /= 0 and kept the comments the same way around!

Answer (score 3):

As a side note if the signal is a vector, then you can do the following:

```
if (A(0)) then
-- it's odd
else
-- it's even
```

Comment: As an added note, type casting is always possible as well, if the type is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
function is_even(val : integer) return boolean is
    constant vec: signed(31 downto 0) := to_signed(val, 32);
begin
   return vec(0) = '0';
end;
```

or

```
function is_even(val : integer) return boolean is
begin
   return val mod 2 = 0;
end;
```

depending on whether your synthesiser is bright enough to figure out `mod 2`

Comment: Do we know of any synthesizer that is not bright enough to figure out mod 2?

Comment: Not that I know of, I'm just paranoid :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you are not storing as an integer * is to register the LSB from the standard logic vector holding the value and check if it is 0 or 1.

EDIT: Re-storing integers

removed * (which can be a problem on many FPGA's)

My mistake here, I was thinking along two different paths and mixed the two up. I have had trouble before passing character and string types between components when coding on FPGA's. While I cannot list the error messages off hand, I took a mental note to use std logic vectors instead of the pre-compile types. I found that they always seemed to work in simulation but never on the board.

Comment: Can you explain why storing as an integer is a problem on FPGAs?